# AMF decoding in Adobe Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, amf

I have a Flex application that receives AMF encoded string from Javascript. The AMF encoded string contains class instances which need to be mapped to classes which have been registered in Flex using class-alias. How can I decode the AMF string within Flex so that the output will be mapped to the corresponding AS3 class?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [cortizone-amf](http://code.google.com/p/cortizone/source/browse/cortizone-amf) library. It has utilities for decoding AMF data. You might especially be interested in the [Amf3Input](http://code.google.com/p/cortizone/source/browse/cortizone-amf/src/main/as3/be/idamf/flash/amf/Amf3Input.as) class.

Comment: Thanks! The Amf3Input class was what I needed.

Comment: Couldn't you just use readObject on the input ByteArray? Why do you need a full blown AMF3 decoding solution when Flash has built-in support for that?